# Should try-finally be used in this case

Tags: java, exception, stack, try-catch

In a DAO layer class, suppose I have code like:

```
private EntityManagerFactory factory;

public void update(T entity) {
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Now in the above code block, RuntimeExceptions might occur (rarely) before the entityManager.close() gets called up. So, will it be good to write it like this:

```
public void update(T entity) {
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(entity);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
     finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Since all the objects in my method are local, they will not exist once the method is over. So, what happens to stack of this method when the exception occurs inside the method?

I think if the stack exists in case of exception, then I do need finally block to close the entityManager. What actually happens?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate or any ORM?

Comment: Well the question is not about hibernate! neither closing it's session. But about scope of method's local variable in case of exceptions.

Comment: Very well, I take it back then :)

Answer (score 7):

> Since all the objects in my method are local, they will not exist once the method is over.

No, the *references* to the objects are local and removed when the method scope is finished, the objects themselves reside on the heap and might eventually be garbage collected. To be safe I'd add the call to close() in the finally statement.

Having a look at the `EntityManager.close()` implementation of Hibernate 4.2.15 (we can't/don't use Hibernate 4.3+ yet but I'd guess it looks similar), the close is passed to the session, the transaction coordinator and - if enabled - the statistics collector. All of those classes will do some cleanup on their own, be it clearing the first level cache, closing database connections, collecting session statistics etc.

Comment: Okay, I see. Is scope of method finished when exception is thrown inside the method?

Comment: @AnmolGupta if the exception leaves the method (i.e. it is not caught or it is rethrown) then yes, the method scope will be left and the finally block will be executed.

Answer (score 4):

> Since all the objects in my method are local, they will not exist once
> the method is over.

In Java, objects exist until the garbage collector destroys them. That's not necessarily motivated by the finalization of the scope where a reference to the object is declared (In general, you're not able to predict when an object is going to be garbage collected). Therefore, you should close the EntityManager.

Comment: EntityManager does not implement AutoCloseable interface.

Comment: Tks @gagarwa. Removed that part.

Answer (score 3):

To my bewilderment, literally all examples I have found don't use the finally clause. Even in the official documentation of Hibernate or JPA.

In my opinion, the correct code should always use the finally clause. I did not map an Entity correctly to the database table and the (Java SE) application hanged when not using finally clause.

Neither `EntityManagerFactory` nor `EntityManager` can be used with try-with-resources as some suggested; they are not `AutoCloseable`.

**Edit** I have found an example which is [doing it correctly](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-and-jpa-2-persist-find-merge-and-remove-example). Heureka.

```
package com.zetcode;

import com.zetcode.model.City;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class Application {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "my-pu";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

        try {

            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM City c");
            List<City> countries = query.getResultList();

            countries.stream().forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x));

            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        } finally {

            entityManager.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely a good way of tackling this issue. Another way would be to extend the `EntityManagerFactory` and implement them as `AutoClosable`. [example](https://medium.com/@priya104/the-autocloseable-interface-404ce6edee85)

Answer (score 1):

> RuntimeExceptions might occur (rarely) before the
>   entityManager.close() gets called up

If you can do anything to handle the `RuntimeException` you expect then you can even catch and handle them. If you cannot even in that case having finally will be safe option so as to close the resource. If it (`EntityManager`) implements `Closeable` interface you can also consider `try-with-resource` statement which invokes close automatically.